# Ionic home page redirect is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

#### Code:

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="segment" color="primary">
    <ion-segment-button value="Home" (click)="page_redirect('HomePage')" text-center> Home </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="Featured" (click)="page_redirect('FeaturedItemPage')" text-center> Featured </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="Category" (click)="page_redirect('CategoriesPage')" text-center> Category </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="User" user text-center> User </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

page_redirect function:

```
page_redirect(page){
    this.navCtrl.push(page);
}
```

#### Error:

> Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: HomePage

Can anyone please tell me why ionic Homepage redirection is not working? `CategoriesPage` and `FeaturedItemPage` redirections are working like a charm.

Comment: Are you using lazy-loading or not .... if possible then show code app.module.ts and homepage.ts

Comment: post your ts page

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me sometimes. Stopping and starting the server with "ionic serve" seems to solve the issue.

And just just to be sure check the name of your page to be exactly **HomePage**